# Tkinter OptionMenu not updating as I add values

Tags: python, database, tkinter

I have linked my tkinter program to a database I created using sqlite3. When I run my program I click on the first option from my menu (1st button - class: AddClass) to the Page 1. Here I can add and submit a typed in value, which is added to my database under the 'Name' column.
I expect to go back to the menu and click on the second page (2nd button - class: AddStudent) where a OptionMenu (dropdown) list is displayed. It should hold all the 'Name' values from my database but doesn't hold the value I just added.

If I close and reopen my program the value has been added to my OptionMenu, but I want it to be added to the dropdown as soon as I submit the typed in value.

How can I do this?
Code:
***Tkinter Program***

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('school.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

largeFont = ("Verdana",20)
mediumFont = font = ("Verdana",15)

class backEnd(tk.Tk): # pass in Tk module of tk

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand = True)

        self.frames = {} # empty dict to store frames - when needed the frame is
        # brought to the top

        self.frames[Menu] = Menu(parent = container, controller = self)
        self.frames[Menu].grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'nesw')

        self.frames[AddClass] = AddClass(parent = container, controller = self)
        self.frames[AddClass].grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'nesw')

        self.frames[AddStudent] = AddStudent(parent = container,controller = self)
        self.frames[AddStudent].grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'nesw')

        # open Menu as soon as program run
        self.showFrame(Menu)

    def showFrame(self, pageName):
        frame = self.frames[pageName]
        frame.tkraise()

class Menu(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        addValue = tk.Button(self, text = 'Add Value to Database', height = 3, width = 60, command = lambda: self.controller.showFrame(AddClass))
        addValue.pack(side = tk.TOP, pady = (175,20))
        dropdown = tk.Button(self, text = 'Dropdown List of Database Values', height = 3, width = 60, command = lambda: self.controller.showFrame(AddStudent))
        dropdown.pack(side = tk.TOP, pady = 20)

class AddClass(tk.Frame): # ADD VALUE TO DROPDOWN

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        self.valueLabel = tk.Label(self, text = 'Value:', font = largeFont)
        self.valueLabel.grid(column = 1, row = 1, padx = (50,10), pady = (50,25), sticky = 'w')
        self.valueNameBox = tk.Entry(self,width = 30, font = mediumFont)
        self.valueNameBox.grid(column = 2, row = 1, pady = (50,25))

        self.backButton = tk.Button(self, text = 'Back', font = mediumFont, command = lambda: self.controller.showFrame(Menu))
        self.backButton.grid(column = 1, row = 7, padx = (50,0), pady = 25, sticky = 'w')
        self.submitButton = tk.Button(self, text = 'Submit', font = mediumFont,
         command = self.addValues)
        self.submitButton.grid(column = 2, row = 7, padx = (50,0), pady = 25, sticky = 'e')

    def addValues(self):
        className = self.valueNameBox.get()
        with conn:
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO classes VALUES (?,?,?)", (className, 'VAL1', '0'))
        acceptanceMessage = tk.Label(self, text = 'Value added', font = mediumFont)
        acceptanceMessage.grid(column = 1, padx = (50,0), row = 9, sticky = 'w')


class AddStudent(tk.Frame): #ADD VALUE TO DROPDOWN

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        self.values = [Name[0] for Name in cursor.execute("SELECT Name FROM classes")]
        # self.classes does not include value added just before this page clicked
        # (if i add a value then go on this page, the value i added is not here)
        # if i close and reopen the program, the value appears

        self.valueNameMenuLabel = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.valueNameMenuLabel.set('Values')

        self.valueLabel = tk.Label(self, text = 'Value:', font = largeFont)
        self.valueLabel.grid(column = 1, row = 5, padx = (50,0), pady = 25, sticky = 'w')
        self.valueList = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.valueNameMenuLabel, *self.values)
        self.valueList.config(font = mediumFont)
        self.valueList.grid(column = 2, row = 5, pady = 25, sticky = 'w')

app = backEnd() # equivilant of root = Tk (since backEnd() inherits from Tk)
app.state('zoomed') # makes window fullscreen
app.mainloop()
```

***Database***

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('school.db') # connects to a database
                                    # (creates db if doesnt exist)
cursor = conn.cursor() # object that allows us to edit db
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS classes
                (Name TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                [Year Group] TEXT NOT NULL,
                [Max Size] INTEGER NOT NULL)''') # ignore 2nd and 3rd column

conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

Comment: The `AddStudent` page has already been created before you add new name to the database.  So the dropdown which is created along with the page will not contain the newly added name.  You need to find a way to update the dropdown list after adding new name to database.  One way to do it is inside the `addValues()` function.

Comment: Thanks the problem makes more sence now, I tried this but it still initialises the page with the un-updated list.